# Print to file and console c++

Tags: c++, fstream, ostream

I am trying to logg my events so i thought of using ostringstream to save the output and then send it to a function where i print the output on screen and on file fstream fileOut. It wont work, it just gives me random numbers and seem not to output all new outputs on the same file but just creates a new file everytime and deletes what was on it before. How do i do this?

where the print happens:

```
void Event::output(ostringstream* info) {
    std::cout << info << std::endl;
    fileOut << info << std::endl;
}
```

where the output happens:

```
ostringstream o;
if (time < SIM_TIME) {

    if (status->tryAssemble(train)) {
        Time ct;
        ct.fromMinutes(time);
        o << ct << " Train [" << train->getTrainNumber() << "] ";

        Time t(0, DELAY_TIME);
        o << "(ASSEMBLED) from " << train->getStart() << " " << train->getScheduledStartTime() <<
            " (" << train->getStartTime() << ") to " << train->getDest() << " " << train->getScheduledDestTime() <<
            " (" << train->getDestTime() << ") delay (" << train->getDelay() << ") speed=" << train->getScheduledSpeed() <<
            " km/h is now assembled, arriving at the plateform at " << train->getStartTime() - t << endl << endl;

        fileOut.open("testfile.txt", std::ios::out);
        if (!fileOut.is_open()) 
            exit(1);            //could not open file
            output(&o);
        train->setStatus(ASSEMBLED);
        time += ASSEMBLE_TIME;
        Event *event = new ReadyEvent(simulation, status, time, train);
        simulation->addEvent(event);
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the output?

Comment: @user1118321 0056F428 is the only thing that gets printed on console and file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It wont work, it just gives me random numbers

You are passing the `ostringstream` to your function by pointer.  There is no `operator<<` that takes an `ostringstream*` pointer as input and prints its string content.  But there is an `operator<<` that takes a `void*` as input and prints the memory address that the pointer is pointing at.  That is the "random numbers" you are seeing.  ANY type of pointer can be assigned to a `void*` pointer.

You need to dereference the `ostringstream*` pointer to access the actual `ostringstream` object.  Even so, there is still no `operator<<` that takes an `ostringstream` as input.  However, `ostringstream` has a `str()` method that returns a `std::string`, and there is an `operator<<` for printing a `std::string`:

```
void Event::output(ostringstream* info) {
    std::string s = info->str();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    fileOut << s << std::endl;
}
```

That being said, you should pass the `ostringstream` by const reference instead of by pointer, since the function does not allow a null `ostringstream` to be passed in, and it does not modify the `ostringstream` in any way:

```
void Event::output(const ostringstream &info) {
    std::string s = info.str();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    fileOut << s << std::endl;
}

...

output(o);
```

> seem not to output all new outputs on the same file but just creates a new file everytime and deletes what was on it before.

That is because you are not opening the file with either the `app` or `ate` flag <sup>1</sup>, so it creates a new file each time, discarding the contents of any existing file.  If you want to append to an existing file instead, you need to either:

- use the `ate` flag to "seek to the end of stream immediately after open":

  ```
  fileOut.open("testfile.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::ate);
  ```
- use the `app` flag to "seek to the end of stream before each write":

  ```
  fileOut.open("testfile.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
  ```

<sup>1: if `fileOut` is a `std::ofstream`, you do not need to specify `std::ios::out` explicitly.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Everything is fine now except of the ios::ate, it still does an overwrite...
I have above every output:
 fileOut.open("testfile.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::ate);

Comment: Then use `app` instead of `ate`